# Why is generic type information lost in generic functions with a Comparable constraint?

Tags: swift

When creating a normal generic function without constraints it works as intended, i.e:

```
func select<T,U>(x:T, f:(T) -> U) -> U {
    return f(x)
}
```

The type flows through into the closure argument where it lets me access it as the strong type, i.e:

```
var b1:Bool = select("ABC") { $0.hasPrefix("A") }
var b2:Bool = select(10) { $0 > 0 }
```

It continues to work when I add an `Equatable` constraint:

```
func selectEquatable<T : Equatable, U : Equatable>(x:T, f:(T) -> U) -> U {
    return f(x)
}

var b3:Bool = selectEquatable("ABC") { $0.hasPrefix("A") }
```

But for some reason fails when using a `Comparable` constraint:

```
func selectComparable<T : Comparable, U : Comparable>(x:T, f:(T) -> U) -> U {
    return f(x)
}

var b4:Bool = selectComparable("ABC") { $0.hasPrefix("A") }
```

Fails with the build error:

> Could not find member 'hasPrefix'

But it does allow returning itself where the type flows through as a `String`

```
var b5:String = selectComparable("ABC") { $0 }
```

Looking at the API docs shows that String is `Comparable`:

```
extension String : Comparable {
}
```

and it even allows implicit casting from a String to a `Comparable`:

```
var str:Comparable = ""
```

So why can't I access it as a strong-typed String inside my Closure?

```
var b4:Bool = selectComparable("ABC") { $0.hasPrefix("A") } //build error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `String`. Your closure `{ $0.hasPrefix("A") }` has the return type `Bool`, which is assigned to `U`. `Bool` is `Equatable`, but not `Comparable`.

You probably want the closure to return `Bool`, but `selectComparable` to return `U`.

#### Edit

Here's evidence that returning a `String` (which is `Comparable`) instead of a `Bool` (not `Comparable`) will compile:

```
func selectComparable<T: Comparable, U: Comparable>(x:T, f:(T) -> U) -> U {
    return f(x)
}
var b4 = selectComparable("ABC") { (str: String) -> String in str }
```

Comment: This is not the issue. The response of `$0.hasPrefix("A")` is a `Bool` (and as as described in the question it works as intended when it's Equatable). It's still the same issue when the type is removed `var b4 = selectComparable("ABC") { $0.hasPrefix("A") }`

Comment: It doesn't matter what method I call on string, i.e. `{ $0.startIndex }` it still works when its `Equatable` but fails when `Comparable` with the same build error: `Could not find member 'x'`

Comment: The problem you described in the posted code is that you return a `Bool`. `Could not find member` is a different problem. I'll edit my question to prove that returning a `String` will make it compile, but I consider the downvote rude enough that I'm not interested in helping further.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectComparable declaration is incorrect.

```
func selectComparable<T: Comparable, U: Comparable>(x:T, f:(T) -> U) -> U {
    return f(x)
}
```

U: Comparable cannot hold for type Bool, it is not Comparable, only Equatable

This will work fine

```
func selectComparable<T: Comparable, U>(x:T, f:(T) -> U) -> U {
    return f(x)
}
```

as will

```
func select<T:Comparable,U: Equatable>(x:T, f:(T) -> U) -> U {
    return f(x)
}
```